# Getting the error Working outside of application context

Tags: python, flask

I have struggled with this and read several articles and none seem to work for me I have used "with app.app_context():" right after the Flask call and it does not work.  I am trying to print out the context before it hits the route.  Please help.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/user1/Documents/PycharmProjects/file_upload2/app/wsgi.py",
> line 7, in 
> app = create_app()   File "/Users/user1/Documents/PycharmProjects/file_upload2/app/flask_project/**init**.py",
> line 105, in create_app
> from .uploads import uploads   File "/Users/user1/Documents/PycharmProjects/file_upload2/app/flask_project/uploads.py",
> line 13, in 
> print(current_app.config.get("MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH"))   File "/Users/user1/Documents/VENV/file_upload2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py",
> line 316, in **get**
> obj = instance._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[misc]   File "/Users/user1/Documents/VENV/file_upload2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py",
> line 513, in _get_current_object
> raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

```
################################################################################
# init.py                                                                      #
################################################################################
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # upload options
    file_mb_max = 100  # in MB
    # app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = file_mb_max * 1024 * 1024  # tried this
    MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH = file_mb_max * 1024 * 1024

    # Register Blueprints
    from .uploads import uploads
    app.register_blueprint(uploads, url_prefix='/upload/')


    return app

################################################################################
# wsgi.py                                                                      #
################################################################################
from flask_project import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

################################################################################
# uploads.py                                                                   #
################################################################################
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory, Blueprint, flash, current_app

uploads = Blueprint('uploads', __name__)

# Check that the upload folder exists
print(current_app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding the `current_app` you can read from [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/appcontext/#creating-an-application-context):

> Flask automatically pushes an application context when handling a request. View functions, error handlers, and other functions that run during a request will have access to current_app.

If you would include the `print(current_app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'])` in a view (which is a function that runs during a request), then it will work.

Example `uploads.py` with a route "home":

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory, Blueprint, flash, current_app

uploads = Blueprint('uploads', __name__)

@uploads.route("/")
def home():
    print(current_app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'])
    return "OK"
```

To access it you need to navigate to path `/upload/home` of your web server.

Also the `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` should be set as `app.config['var name here']` as you already tried and commented, your `init.py`:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # upload options
    file_mb_max = 100  # in MB
    app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = file_mb_max * 1024 * 1024

    # Register Blueprints
    from .uploads import uploads
    app.register_blueprint(uploads, url_prefix='/upload/')


    return app
```

Answer (score 0):

register your blueprints after create_app() with app.context

```
app = create_app()
with app.app_context():
    from .uploads import uploads
    app.register_blueprint(uploads, url_prefix='/upload')
```